# E1001: Failed to update System image latest Onplus 5T and other

Tags: twrp, lineageos, oneplus-5, oneplus-5t

I downloaded the latest LineageOS for my latest Device, from Dumplings SF.

firmware, recovery, vendor files.

What I get all the time is that error message "E1001: Failed to update system image" and that he can't mount the vendor partition.

Any ideas ? PS: I can't even flash back to latest Oneplus ROM (or even older roms)....

Update:
Meanwhile I use TWRP from "cheeseburgerdumplings" for 8.1 on what lineageOS and the "/vendor" partition is no more tried to be mounted.
What I figure out as well, is that if I go with adbs command to know if the filesystem is encrypted or not:

```
adb shell getprop ro.crypto.state
```

tells me "encrypted"

Now the big question, which filesystems are encrypted, all ?
And which partition or FS does not have to be encrpyted?

Here is the "recovery.log":
https://pastebin.com/raw/tKMStdSF

Screenshot:

[image: TWRP Error Lineagos Oneplus 5T]

Comment: Hi, have you tried to reboot Recovery before flashing ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and solved it by setting the settings flag `Unmount System before installing a ZIP` to false. This is not documented or recommended anywhere, however.

For me, it was LineageOS+MicroG image [serrano3gxx](https://download.lineage.microg.org/serrano3gxx/). If someone else finds this to solve this error, please leave a note so we can report it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Update to the latest official Oneplus 5T Oxygen OS, and use the official recovery and image, and everything goes without any problems.

Update must be done in "offline update mode", as online update server is no more available.